# Why __bridge isn’t needed for constants from frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation, foundation

Today I found that constants from frameworks aren’t needed to have `__bridge` in cast statement. Like:

```
NSString *cast = (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie;
```

where

```
extern const CFStringRef kUTTypeMovie __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_4,__IPHONE_3_0);
```

I researched this thinking that `const` may affect it and was out of luck. Those two require `__bridge` cast:

```
const CFStringRef cf_const;
NSString *ns_const = (NSString *) cf_const; // ARC bridge cast is required

CFStringRef cf_nonconst;
NSString *ns_nonconst = (NSString *) cf_nonconst;  // ARC bridge cast is required
```

So can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

When you see const CFStringRef, that is a constant reference to a string, which means you have a variable containing that reference somewhere, and you are not allowed to assign to the variable. It doesn't mean anything about the CFStringRef itself.

Comment: If I write `const CFStringRef` by myself I’m required to write `__bridge`. If it is defined in framework header, I’m not. That is my question: why am I not required to write `__bridge` in some cases. I understand it works for all toll-free types, not just for `CFStringRef`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting observation.

The case you have discovered is handled specially by the compiler. The details can be found in the section [Conversion to retainable object pointer type of expressions with known semantics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#conversion-to-retainable-object-pointer-type-of-expressions-with-known-semantics) of the Clang documentation. There it states:

> Bridging casts are annoying. Absent the ability to completely automate the management of CF objects, however, we are left with relatively poor attempts to reduce the need for a glut of explicit bridges. Hence these rules.
>
> [...] For loads from const global variables of C retainable pointer type, it is reasonable to assume that global system constants were initialitzed with true constants (e.g. string literals), but user constants might have been initialized with something dynamically allocated, using a global initializer.

The above mentioned assumption relies on the coding practices used by the system (framework), but user-defined globals cannot be assumed to follow the same practices so an explicit bridge cast is required.

HTH